# PHP IMAP connection speed

Tags: php, imap

this is my first experimentations with imap in php.

I am making a panel for my company, where I upload the clientes, with name and email, and asignit to users,

so when an user enters the panel and have a client there, the panel check the user email account and search for emails from the client email,

my problem is that the first time I load the panel it gets very slow, it takes 5 sec to 15 secs to load (or more sometimes) but after the first load, it is fast, but if I go away for let's say 10 minutes and reload the panel it gets slow again for the first time.

this is my code; for each user in the panel I call this function:

```
function mostrarCorreosRelacionados($remitente){
$hostname = '{localhost:143}INBOX';
$correo = explode("|||",$_SESSION['correo']);
$username = $correo[0];
$password = $correo[1];

/* Intento de conexión */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('No se pudo conectar con: usuario: '.$username.' y clave: '.$password.' ' . imap_last_error());

/* Recuperamos los emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'FROM "'.$remitente.'"');


/* Si obtenemos los emails, accedemos uno a uno... */
if($emails) {

    /* variable de salida */
    $output = '';

    /* Colocamos los nuevos emails arriba */
    rsort($emails);

    /* por cada email... */
    $ii=0;
    foreach($emails as $email_number) {

        /* Obtenemos la información específica para este email */
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
        //$body = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,4);

        $uid = imap_uid($inbox, $email_number);

        $header = imap_header($inbox,$email_number);
        $fromInfo = $header->from[0];
        $replyInfo = $header->reply_to[0];


        $details = array(
            "fromAddr" => (isset($fromInfo->mailbox) && isset($fromInfo->host))
                ? $fromInfo->mailbox . "@" . $fromInfo->host : "",
            "fromName" => (isset($fromInfo->personal))
                ? $fromInfo->personal : "",
            "replyAddr" => (isset($replyInfo->mailbox) && isset($replyInfo->host))
                ? $replyInfo->mailbox . "@" . $replyInfo->host : "",
            "replyName" => (isset($replyTo->personal))
                ? $replyto->personal : "",
            "subject" => (isset($header->subject))
                ? $header->subject : "",
            "udate" => (isset($header->udate))
                ? $header->udate : ""
        );

        //$message = mail_mime_to_array($inbox,$email_number);



        /* Mostramos la información de la cabecera del email */

        $output.= '<li>';

        $output.= '<div class="encabezadoMail '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';

        $output.= '<span class="subject">Asunto: '.decodificarTexto($details["subject"]).'</span><br />';

        $output.= '<a href="mailto:'.$fromInfo->mailbox.'@'.$fromInfo->host.'" class="from" title="'.$fromInfo->mailbox.'@'.$fromInfo->host.'">'.decodificarTexto($fromInfo->personal).'</a><br />';

        $output.= '<span class="textoChico">'.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';

        $output.= '</div>';



        /* Mostramos el mensaje del email */

        $output.= '<div class="cuerpoMail" id="msg_'.$i.'" style="display:none;">'.utf8_encode(getBody($uid,$inbox)).'</div>';

        $output.= '</li>';




        $ii++;
    }



    print '<ul class="emails"><li class="encabezadoMail"><strong>E-mails</strong></li>'.$output.'</ul>';

} 



/* Cerramos la connexión */

imap_close($inbox);
}
```

in the imap_open I have tried localhost,   domain and ip, but all seems to work the same.

any ideas???

UPDATE TO MONKEYZEUS

I did what you told me and here is what I got:

FIST CLIENT

conexión: 0.0309870243073 seconds
Recuperamos: 26.7151398659 seconds

SECOND CLIENT

conexión: 0.102792978287 seconds
Recuperamos: 0.0511429309845 seconds

THIRD CLIENT

conexión: 0.00676202774048 seconds
Recuperamos: 0.0503911972046 seconds

it just happens in the first time, and if I press F5 the long time I got on the first client does not happends, it load fast as the others, if I wait 10 minutes it gets slow again in the first client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to figure out what is taking the longest.

I will guess it is this part:

```
/* Intento de conexión */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('No se pudo conectar con: usuario: '.$username.' y clave: '.$password.' ' . imap_last_error());

/* Recuperamos los emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'FROM "'.$remitente.'"');
```

So try benchmarking it:

```
$start = microtime(true); // start timer

/* Intento de conexión */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('No se pudo conectar con: usuario: '.$username.' y clave: '.$password.' ' . imap_last_error());

echo 'conexión: '.(microtime(true)-$start).' seconds<br>'; // show results

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------

$start = microtime(true); // start timer again

/* Recuperamos los emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'FROM "'.$remitente.'"');

echo 'Recuperamos: '.(microtime(true)-$start).' seconds<br>'; // show new results
```

**conexión** is probably the slowest part. This could be because of your mail server.

### UPDATE

According to your benchmarks it is clear that `imap_search()` is the slowest part.

This is because it is performing a database search and you have these possible issues:

- Your mail server's hardware is very weak
- Your mail server has 100's of gigabytes of data/email so the query naturally slows down
- You are running out of hard drive space on the mail server

The reason it goes fast the second time is because databases perform something called caching so the results of the query were loaded into memory (RAM) but after 10 minutes that cache is either cleared by the database or a change occurred to the data so the query needs to be re-cached.

Comment: What does `'FROM "'.$remitente.'"'` look like? Is there a `WHERE` clause in there? If there is no `WHERE` clause then you are fetching EVERYONES email when you only needed a specific user.

Comment: using echo 'Recuperamos '.$remitente.' :'.(microtime(true)-$start).' seconds<br>'; // show new results

I get this:   conexión: 0.00506997108459 seconds
Recuperamos tarashanti19@adinet.com.uy :1.65491604805 seconds

since this only happen after a period of inactivity and it only happends with the first $remitente.. is possible that it is the imap server that is taking that long?

Comment: Just read the update, so it is the mail server ins't?  the server a shared windows hosting in hostgator.  do I have someway to speed this up? or not? the difference in localhost vs domain name vs ip in the imap_open is important?

Comment: I cannot understand your comment, please use back-ticks `\`` for code like this `\`microtime(true)\``

Comment: The mail server is the problem for your code. You will need to contact HostGator to see if they have anything more powerful for you but it will cost money.

Comment: ... thank you MonkeyZeus, I guess I will mask the problem loading the emails with ajax.

Comment: You are welcome. You should still try calling them, maybe HostGator knows some tricks to make it faster without charging you money =) Good Luck!

Comment: A typical (non-enterprise) IMAP server does not actually use a database for searches.  Therefore, when you do a search FROM, it has to open every email in the INBOX.  It may cache this information which is why repeated searches may be faster, but after 10 minutes the server probably winds down.

Comment: @Max Thank you. A database is a base of data even if it's not a well known RDBMS. It might be rudimentary but there is certainly some incarnation of SQL usage and information caching. You will notice that my answer does address the caching theory as well..

Comment: A typical Unix server using mbox or Maildir is not likely based on SQL in any way. Very few people would think of mbox format as a database, even if it is by the strictest definition of the word.

Comment: I ended up fetching headers of all mesages, and indexing them into a mysql database, so now I do the search in the mysqli database instead of the imap search.

Comment: @AlvaroHernandorena Good thinking, that sounds like a much more stable and consistent solution compared to masking with AJAX!